# Copying Mongodb gives SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (shell):1

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to copy a MongoDB database from my (local) development machine to my (remote) test server.

When I am logged in to my test server, I do the following:

> db.copyDatabase("myDB","myDB",xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx);

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my external IP.

I get the error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (shell):1

Which doesn't seem to make sense. I've tried adding an extra ) (although I was pretty sure that wasn't actually going to solve it ) but funnily it gives exactly the same error. I'm totally stumped since it seems to make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is getting confused when it sees the first decimal point (doesn't know how to parse that as a parameter).  You just need to wrap the IP address in quotes.

```
db.copyDatabase("myDB","myDB", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be correct - now my issue is "couldn't connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ;) the search continues

Comment: @Ankur maybe your server's firewall is blocking it?  Remember Mongo runs on some crazy port (27017) by default.

Comment: thanks again - I know this is really off topic - but do you know how I can check if a firewall is blocking something, I'll look it up myself, but if its something simple and you know I'd appreciate it. If I get totally stuck I'll ask another question.

Comment: It's ok, there's plenty of info on the WWW :)

Comment: @Ankur I'd suggest (as you say) opening another question for this and putting in all the relevant detail.  In general though, I would check 1) is the server responsive at all (ping, web request)?  2) Are you sure Mongo is running on the server? (eg, can you connect to it locally from the server)  3) If 1 and 2 are ok, then firewall issue seems likely.